# DataTables multiple styles on multiple tables in one page

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I am new to datatables and needed to get mutliple datatables working in the same page
I found a online JSBIN of the multiple tables so i can play around with the styling..

Here is the forked  JSBIN demo http://jsbin.com/qawota/1/edit

I am trying to have multiple styles applied to the diffrent headers of the tables. For example the inner most table i would like to change the headings to have colored backgrounds etc.. anything to make it look diffrent so it is not confusing to people using the table

I have given the inner table an id of example1 and a class of innerDataTable but in the css writing something like .innerDataTable or trying to select with the id has no effect.

Thanks

Comment: just need more specific rules like `table table th{..}` Won't affect the top level table

Comment: Hmm I am trying more specific rules but i can't seem to get the selector quite right, could you show me in the JSBIN

I am trying something like `innerDataTable.table.datatable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Jquery **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** to change **css styling of the page**.

I have updated your example adding a button that **onClick** changes heading background.

Html:

```
<a id="change_style" onClick="change_style();">Change style</a>
```

Js:

```
function change_style() { 
  $('#example tr[role="row"]').css('background','red');
}
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/forenisedevu/1/edit

Comment: hmm that applies it to all of the tables, i just want to try and target the inner most one.. with the id=example1 and class innerDataTable. Modifying your JSBIN with the updated id does not seem to work

Comment: The problem is that `#example1` doesn't appended to the code. If you add the id / class to the tr / th it works just fine. It's because table id created in the js code `function fnFormatDetails()` / `function fnFormatDetails1()`. You have to alter these functions to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! i just need to select: the following
`$('#doubleinner'+iPos+'_'+jPos+'tr[role="row"]').css('background','red');`